# laravel route on logged in not triggering

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to route the index page to a different location if logged in however even though my authentication system works, it's not redirecting to where I expected i.e. getLogged, instead it always redirects to getIndex whether I am logged in or not.

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (!Sentry::check()) return Redirect::to('/');
});

Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function() {
  Route::get('/', array('uses' => 'MyController@getLogged'));
});

Route::get('/', array('before' => 'detectLang', 'uses' => 'MyController@getIndex'));
```

I tested to make sure my auth works by changing

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function() {
  Route::get('/', array('uses' => 'MyController@getLogged'));
});
```

to

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function() {
  Route::get('/dash', array('uses' => 'MyController@getLogged'));
});
```

and that properly behaves that I can only access /dash when I am logged in so why is my index route not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're declaring the same route twice, it won't work. To achieve this functionality, instead of adding a `auth` filter, add a `guest` one that, instead of checking if the user is **not connected**, will check if it **is**. Something like this:

```
Route::filter('guest', function () {
    if (Sentry::check()) return Redirect::route('logged');
});
```

Then, setup your routes, something along these lines:

```
Route::get('/', array(
    'as'     => 'home',
    'uses'   => 'MyController@getIndex',
    'before' => 'guest'
));

Route::get('/logged', array(
    'as'     => 'logged',
    'uses'   => 'MyController@getLogged',
    'before' => 'auth|detectLang'
));
```

**Note:** The `as` key gives a name to your route, so you can use it on `Redirect::route` or `URL::route` methods.

Comment: Thanks Raphael, my situation though is that the login form is inside the index page '/', I just want it to redirect to a different page if logged in and not see the index page, where do I put that redirect?

Comment: You want to do that without changing the URL?

Comment: Scenario is, a user goes on the index page, logs in, the user is redirect to /account. Now if the user revisits / it will again auto redirect to /account because the user is logged in. Where do I set this up? I'm trying now inside the constructor of my index controller   
    if (Sentry::check())  return Redirect::to('account'); but it's not working

Comment: Ah perfect! thank you! While debugging I noticed something weird,  this redirect would not work if it's inside my constructor  but it works if it's inside an actual method in that controller if (Sentry::check()) return Redirect::to('account');